# Swift: CoreData load my image (portrait) at 90 degrees

Tags: swift, core-data, uiimagepickercontroller

When I save, my image to coreData, when I re-open it from CoreData, all image who was took in portrait, are in landscape orientation.

I fund lot of previews question a bout it but all in Objective C not in Swift.

How can I fix the problem?

This is my code: ( it is also a text application when it work I will add it to my project)

This text app has two image view one for loading from library and one for loading from coreData.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

    var monimage: String!

        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    @IBOutlet weak var MaPhoto: UIImageView? = UIImageView()
    @IBOutlet weak var maPhoto2: UIImageView! = UIImageView()

    var cameraUI:UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    var yourContacts:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

      imagePicker.delegate = self

        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func LabraryImage(sender: AnyObject) {

        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func takePhoto(sender: UIButton) {

        if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera)){

            cameraUI = UIImagePickerController()
            cameraUI.delegate = self
            cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            cameraUI.allowsEditing = true

            self.presentViewController(cameraUI, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }else{
            //no camera available
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "There is no camera available", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .Default, handler: {(alertAction)in
                alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated (true, completion: nil)
            }))
        }

    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            MaPhoto!.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            MaPhoto!.image = pickedImage
        }

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func btnSavePressed(sender : AnyObject) {

        let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("ImageData", inManagedObjectContext: context)

        var newUser = ImageData (entity: ent!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

          let contactImageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(MaPhoto!.image)

            newUser.monimage = contactImageData

            context.save(nil)
      self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)   
    }

    @IBAction func loadImage(sender: AnyObject){

        let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        let request2 = NSFetchRequest (entityName: "ImageData")
        request2.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;

        var results2:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request2, error: nil)!

        if results2.count > 0 {
            for user in results2{
                var thisUser2 = user as! ImageData


        let profileImage:UIImage = UIImage(data: thisUser2.monimage)!

                maPhoto2.image = profileImage

            }
        }

    }
```

I also working to get the image square so it is for that "allowEditing is = true"

Comment: please add your code, how u r saving the image and getting it from core data.

Comment: I gess it is easer with something to look at it!

Comment: You are saying `let contactImageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(MaPhoto!.image)`. That's fine, but when you do that, the image data is stripped of any information about orientation — there is no EXIF info in a PNG. So if you want to keep the orientation information, then keep it! But this will have to be a separate step. Or, save it as a JPEG, not as a PNG; a JPEG has EXIF information.

Comment: I understand now, thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Thank s for your help!

this is the answer to my question:

> ```
> @IBAction func btnSavePressed(sender : AnyObject) {
>     let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
>     let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
> ```

```
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("ImageData",
        inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let options = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
        insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    var newImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(MaPhoto!.image,1)

    options.setValue(newImageData, forKey: "monimage")

    var error: NSError?
    managedContext.save(&error)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

JPGs are great for photos. However, saving in jpeg might loose some quality which png tends to excel as it has a lossless compression format.

Its just a matter of preference and what you need at the moment. If you don't want to convert to jpg you can call this method then convert to pngData to preserve orientation before saving to coreData. :)

```
func rotatedCopy() -> UIImage {
    if self.imageOrientation == UIImage.Orientation.up {
        return self
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

    //draws the image in current context respecting orientation
    draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))

    let copy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return copy!
}
```